# Check login attempts

Tags: php, authentication

I have a login form and I want to check the failed login attempts and take appropriate action, based on the attempts.

**I was thinking along these lines:**

1. The minimum allowed time between consecutive failed attempts will be 1 sec.
2. When there is a failed attempt, first delete the older entries in the db which happened before 1 sec.
3. If greater than 1 sec, then after a particular number of attempts(lets say 3), display a message to the user asking him if he wants to reset the password or try again(similar to facebook).
4. If the last login attempt happened in less than 1 sec, then block the ip address for 15 minutes.

I have **already gone through the other posts on this website** and I have seen people using different approaches like showing captcha or using cookies and other methods.

So my question is what is the best method (or a standard method) of approaching this problem?

Answer (score 1):

On your user/member table add two new columns: "last login date(time)" and "number of login attempts".

For a login attempt, set "last login date" to current date and increment "number of login attempts". You can then check for each attempt if the max number of attempts has been exceeded, or if the attempt happened too quickly. Though from the sound of things you perhaps want a mixture of client-side and server-side validation for the timed attempts.

On successful login you clear "number of login attempts".